Upper Bound on the Magnitude of the Action of the Chebyshev Derivative Matrix
The Chebyshev derivative matrix $D$ is used in numerical analysis as a substitute for differentiation. When $u$ is a vector, $Du$ represents the differentiation action of $u$. For example, if $u$ is a constant vector, then $Du = 0$.
The precise definition of the Chebyshev derivative matrix $D$ can be found in the publication by Lloyd N. Trefethen, titled "Spectral Methods in MATLAB," published by the Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics in 2000.
Since $D$ is a matrix, it naturally follows that $\lVert Du \rVert \leq \lVert D \rVert \lVert u \rVert$. However, this upper bound isn't very useful. The reason being that $D$ isn't a regular matrix but one that calculates the rate of change between consecutive points. Therefore, if we translate $u$ to $u' = u + \beta$ where $\beta$ is a constant vector, as $\beta$ increases, (LHS) $\lVert Du'\rVert = \lVert Du \rVert$ remains the same, but (RHS) $\lVert u' \rVert$ can increase indefinitely.
Has any research been conducted to find an upper bound on $\lVert Du \rVert$ that accurately reflects the magnitude of differentiation?
Thank you.

Your question doesn't really make sense to me. Can you clarify what you mean in the sentence 'if we translate $u$ to $u' = u + \beta$ ... but $| u' |$ can increase indefinitely'? And what equation are you referring to when you write LHS and RHS?

Hello, thank you. I mean LHS is $\lVert D u \rVert$ and RHS is $\lVert D \rVert$$\lVert u \rVert$ . If we increase $\beta$, then the norm of $ u + \beta$ increase but  $\lVert D u' \rVert$ does not increase because $\lVert D u' \rVert = \lVert D u + D \beta \rVert$ and $D \beta = 0 $.
